# How can i find out how many times a loop was executed in each if condition inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

Hey guys i need your help with this exercise.

I have this array and i need to print out each Positive, Negative, Zero number and then after that i need to print out the number of the numbers in each process for example the positive numbers count is 2

Can you help me please to do that ?

Full Code :

```html
<style>
    body {
        background: #333;
    }
</style>

<?php

$numbers = [10, 20, -20, -30, 0, 0, 0];
echo "<ul>";

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if ($number > 0) {
        echo "<li style='color: #080;'>Positive Number :  {$number}</li><br />";
    } elseif ($number == 0) {
        echo "<li style='color: #FF0;'>Zero Number :  {$number}</li><br />";
    } elseif  ($number) {
        echo "<li style='color: #F00;'>Negative Number :  {$number}</li><br />";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Thanks guys

Comment: There is no automatic way to do that, you will have to add counter variables, and increment them in your if conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a counter.

```
<style>
    body {
        background: #333;
    }
</style>

<?php

$numbers = [10, 20, -20, -30, 0, 0, 0];
$counts = [0,0,0]; //positive,negative,zero
echo "<ul>";

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if ($number > 0) {
$counts[0]++;
        echo "<li style='color: #080;'>Positive Number :  {$number}</li><br />";
    } elseif ($number == 0) {
$counts[2]++;
        echo "<li style='color: #FF0;'>Zero Number :  {$number}</li><br />";
    } else {
$counts[1]++;
        echo "<li style='color: #F00;'>Negative Number :  {$number}</li><br />";
    }
}
// access here
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare counter variables and increment them inside your if conditions.

```
<style>
    body {
        background: #333;
    }
</style>

<?php

$numbers = [10, 20, -20, -30, 0, 0, 0];
echo "<ul>";

$positiveNumbers = 0;
$negativeNumbers = 0;
$zeros = 0;

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if ($number > 0) {
        $positiveNumbers++;
        echo "<li style='color: #080;'>Positive Number :  {$number}</li><br />";
    } elseif ($number == 0) {
        $zeros++;
        echo "<li style='color: #FF0;'>Zero Number :  {$number}</li><br />";
    } else {
        $negativeNumbers++;
        echo "<li style='color: #F00;'>Negative Number :  {$number}</li><br />";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "Total Positive Numbers: $positiveNumbers<br/>";
echo "Total Negative Numbers: $negativeNumbers<br/>";
echo "Total Zeroes: $zeros<br/>";
```

Comment: If it serves your purpose, please mark it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want o print total number of negative, positive and zero in the array you can do it as below:

```
<style>
    body {
        background: #333;
    }
</style>

<?php

$numbers = [10, 20, -20, -30, 0, 0, 0];
$totalPositive = 0; $totalNegative = 0; $totalZero = 0;

echo "<ul>";

//Firstly count the number of positive, negative and zero
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    if ($number > 0) {
        $totalPositive++;
    } elseif ($number == 0) {
        $totalZero++;
    } else {
        $totalNegative++;
    }
}
//print them all
echo "<li style='color: #080;'>Positive Number :  {$totalPositive}</li><br />";
echo "<li style='color: #FF0;'>Zero Number :  {$totalZero}</li><br />";
echo "<li style='color: #F00;'>Negative Number :  {$totalNegative}</li><br />";
echo "</ul>";
```